# Gradle plugin task ordering

Tags: gradle, build-process

**What I have?**

1. Java source file with Main class (MainApp)
2. gradle build script

   apply plugin: 'application'
   mainClassName = "MainApp"
   sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['.']

So when I do `gradle run`, it executes main method and everything works just perfectly.

```
C:\tmp\gradle-fun>gradle run
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
Hello MainApp !!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**What I want to do?**

Now I was wondering about clean task (common build tasks) to clean the build directory before `run` task executes.

There is reason behind that, I want to make sure that every time gradle should compile the java files and all .class file should be refreshed (its some requirement)

**What I have tried?**

Added a wrapper task which executes clean task and run task in order.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "MainApp"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['.'] 
task exec(dependsOn: ['clean', 'run'])
```

So when I run `gradle exec`, it does it job properly. However I feel that its patch work when you have extra tasks just for ordering execution.

```
C:\tmp\gradle-fun>gradle run
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
Hello MainApp !!
:exec
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**What I would like to know?**

Is there any way to avoid writing wrapper task and do some Gradle magic to achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have the `run` task depend on `clean`. This will ensure your project is cleaned before every run. If you want to be more specific in regards to your use case, you can simply clean the `compileJava` task.

```
run.dependsOn 'cleanCompileJava'
```

**Edit:** To avoid deleting your classes before the run add:

```
classes.mustRunAfter 'cleanCompileJava'
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried the same - but `clean` task is invoked just before `run` - which deletes build directory (which is good) but it deletes recently compiled class. So there will be no main class file to run. :(

Comment: Thanks.. It worked without any patch work (means adding wrapper tasks).

`compileJava.mustRunAfter 'clean'` also does same.

Comment: The `classes` task is really just an aggregate of `compileJava` and `processResources`. It simply ensures that both are done.

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own task, with `clean` and `run` as dependencies:

```
task cleanRun(dependsOn: [clean, run])
```

Or, you could follow Mark Vieira's answer and change the wiring:

```
run.dependsOn 'clean'
classes.mustRunAfter 'clean'
```

The second line makes sure that it doesn't clean the compiled classes.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: What is `classes` referring to?  Javac compilation?

Comment: @Igor exactly, the `classes` task is responsible for compiling all Java files and generating all the `.class` files.

Comment: Does that mean we can reverse this order like this: `clean.mustRunAfter 'classes'`?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, but that means you'd be deleting everything that you built right after you have built it. I don't know if for example you ask it to build a jar file an empty jar is generated because all files to be added were deleted, or if it would just fail, or if it would build the class files again. I'd bet on the first case though.